# Tensorflow tensor_scatter_nd_add indices

Tags: python, tensorflow

What I want to do is to insert some columns into a tf tensor `z`

```
z = tf.zeros((100, 50))
indices = tf.constant([[0], [2]])
updates = tf.ones((50, 2))
tf.tensor_scatter_nd_add(z, indices, updates)
```

is what I want to insert two columns of ones into columns `0` and `2` of axis=1 (columns) into `z`. But I get the error

InvalidArgumentError: Outer dimensions of indices and update must match. Indices shape: [2,1], updates shape:[50,2] [Op:TensorScatterAdd]

How do I control the indices argument to prevent this?